# Correct file path within Spring application

Tags: java, json, spring, filepath

It sounds very odd but last few hours I am trying to write a json file in web app folder in a Spring application from my java class. I have attached snap that may clear the understanding of it. [click to Refer the file system snap here..."jsonfiles" is the folder i am writing files marked with red circle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti4fc.png) Please suggest the correct file path for json file from java class. Thanks in advance. And also suggest is it a good practice to do it? I am new to this kind of scenario.

Java code that is writing to file:

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("../src/main/webaccess/jsonfiles/jsonfile.json")){
file.write(json.toString());
}
```

[image]

Comment: The relevant code must be in the question itself. But anyway, this question makes little sense: when deployed on a server somewhere, all you will have is a war or jar file. That server won't be your developer workstation, and there won't be any src directory, nor any webapp directory. Decide of a directory where you want to write files. Or save your data in a database.

Comment: Thanks JB. I need those files at runtime for populating the charts.. so can u suggest me where(in which location from work space view) can I write json files so can access them at the time of loading the respective pages from html side. So basically it is like i am writing json files from java classes and then using those files to populate my web page charts  so i need a common place where i can write the files and later can access them from web app parts. Also i need data as json files so not going to DB option. Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not the right path to place output (JSON in your case) files within webapp folder.

Reason: During deployment you will loose this change, as war file will be extracted and your webapp folder will get over written.

Correct approach: Write to file system outside your tomcat directory. General practise is to define a environment variable pointing to external directory where your application has write permission and write all your contents there. It's similar to writting log files.

Comment: Thanks Vinod.I need those files at runtime for populating the charts.. so can u suggest me where(in which location from work space view)  can I write json files so can access them at the time of loading the respective pages from html side.

Comment: @prashant again, there won't be any "workspace" on the server where you deploy your application. There will be a file system, and a tomcat server executing your war file. Put them wherever you want on the file system, outside of the tomcat directory. Use a servlet to read them from this directory and send them to the browser when your frontend requests them.

Comment: I think an example would help. For Example you can write in/tmp or /var/log or any custom directory in linux OS. if windows, then C:/Desktop etc

Answer (score 0):

Vinod is correct. I had a similar issue when I tried to configure a Kafka Producer with Spring. Put your temporary files in any folder in the actual file system of your OS/Container like /tmp/myApp . This "/tmp/myApp" directory must have write permission. You have to use this absolute path of the directory when you read/write a file in it.